# Hero Unit Styles not being applied

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am starting a conversation of a psd to html using bootstrap but my hero unit is not getting its default style

```html
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.css" >
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        </head>
        
        
        <body>
        
        
            <div class="hero-unit">
      <h1>We build well desgined websites</h1>
      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
          Get Started
        </a>
          
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
        Learn More
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
            
         
        
        </body>
    </html>
```

You will see here in the image its getting the style of the images ok but ntot the hero unit does anybody have an idea as to why?.

[image]

Comment: Where is the `CSS` hero-unit located? None of your stylesheets has hero-unit. Is it related to this? http://bootstrap-tutorial.bootstraptor.com/post/53197235489/headings-hero-unit

Comment: I am using this tutorial which referes to the hero unit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUoTqF_duxI

Comment: @RonnieOosting I need the nav bar to float over the jumbo tron as per the psd how would i do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uisng twitter bootstrap 3 you should use jumbotron instead of hero-unit

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#jumbotron

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are refering to this CSS: https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css

In case you want to use the hero-unit class, which is bootstrap v2, stylesheet this one.

If you use bootstrap 3, i suggest to use jumbotron as scaisEdge noticed.

If this did not answer your question, you might want to create your own CSS so you can style it the way you want it.

Comment: How would one make the nav bar look like its floating over the jumbotron

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Do you mean this? @David https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h